# Retrofit2: обработка ответа с кодом ошибки HTTP 404

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Хочу достать содержимое ошибки с сервера.
**Сам сервер устроен так, чтобы выдавать код ошибки 404 и отправлять 2 поля с данными.**
Нашёл много способов обработки этой ошибки, но они все разные.
Самая беда в том, что я не достаточно знаком с Retrofit, поэтому методом тыка устал вставлять методы на отлов этих полей ошибки.

Вот эту предпоследнюю строчку пытаюсь достать:

```
    03-16 14:47:19.454 16345-16598/ru.test.app D/Retrofit: {"code":4,"message":"\u041f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0430\u043d \u043d\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u0430\u043c\u0435\u0442\u0440 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c"}
```

Как вообще работает проект:

Запускаю поток -

```
    ((ParentActivity) context).getSpiceManager().execute(new LoginRequest(context, profileEmptyHeaderHolder.inputEmail.getText().toString(), profileEmptyHeaderHolder.inputPassword.getText().toString()), new HolostLoginRequestListener());
```

Ставлю слушатель -

```
private class HolostLoginRequestListener implements RequestListener<LoginResponse> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(LoginResponse baseResponse) {

        if (baseResponse != null) {
            ((ParentActivity) context).getSpiceManager().execute(new LoginRequest(context, profileEmptyHeaderHolder.inputEmail.getText().toString(), profileEmptyHeaderHolder.inputPassword.getText().toString()), new LoginRequestListener());
        } else {
            incorrectData();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс LoginRequest -

```
public class LoginRequest extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<LoginResponse, ServerConnectionService> {

    public LoginRequest(Context context, String email, String password) {
    super(LoginResponse.class, ServerConnectionService.class);
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.context = context;
    this.deviceId =     Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    this.auth = Auth.LOGIN;

    this.city = String.valueOf(SharedPreferencesManager.getCityId(context));
    this.CITY_ID = SharedPreferencesManager.getLocationParam(context);
    }

    @Override
    public LoginResponse loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {

    try {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put(EMAIL, String.valueOf(email));
                map.put(PASSWORD, String.valueOf(password));
                map.put(CITY_ID, city);
                map.put(DEVICE_ID, String.valueOf(deviceId));
                LoginResponse initResponse = getService().loginRequest(map);

                return initResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
              } 
    }
}
```

Интерфейс, откуда беру метод getService().loginRequest(map) -

```
public interface ServerConnectionService {
    @POST("/v1/login")
    LoginResponse loginRequest(@QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap);
}
```

Это класс, от которого наследуется LoginResponse (который в интерфейсе) -

```
@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)

public class BaseResponse implements Parcelable {

@JsonProperty(value = "code")
private String code;

@JsonProperty(value = "message")
private String message;

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public BaseResponse()
{
    super();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.code);
    dest.writeString(this.message);
}

protected BaseResponse(Parcel in) {
    this.code = in.readString();
    this.message = in.readString();
}
}
```

Так создаю объект класса для работы с Retrofit -

```
private SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(BaseSpiceService.class);
```

И сам класс BaseSpiceService -

```
public class BaseSpiceService extends RetrofitJackson2SpiceService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    addRetrofitInterface(ServerConnectionService.class);
}

@Override
protected String getServerUrl() {
    return "http://test.ru/api";
}


@Override
protected RestAdapter.Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
    final long timeOut = 10;

    final OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    httpClient.setConnectTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.setReadTimeout(timeOut * 2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
//        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL, false)
            .configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, false)
            .configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS, false)
            .configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS, false);

    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Test/ru.test.app");
        }
    };


    final RestAdapter.Builder restAdapterBuilder = super.createRestAdapterBuilder()
            .setClient(new OkClient(httpClient))
            .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(mapper))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor);

    return restAdapterBuilder;
}

@Override
protected NetworkStateChecker getNetworkStateChecker() {
    return new NetworkStateChecker() {

        @Override
        public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
            //не проверяем на наличие сети
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkPermissions(Context context) {
        }
    };
}
}
```

Пытался в классе BaseSpiceService у разных обьектов вывести методы onRequest/onFailure, не вышло.

Потом пытался в LoginRequest в catch создавать объект Call по ответам в англоязычном форуме SO, у этого объекта были методы -

```
Call<ResponseBody> myCall = getService().loginRequest1(map);
                myCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            try {
                                String myString = response.body().string();
                                Log.e("TAG", "LoginRequest.loadDataFromNetwork.onResponse.NotSuccessful: " + myString);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        String myString = call.toString();
                        Log.e("TAG", "LoginRequest.loadDataFromNetwork.onResponse.onFailure: " + myString);
                    }
                });
```

но система почему-то ругалась на `getService().loginRequest1(map);`

А метод был таким в интерфейсе -

```
@POST("/v1/login")
Call<ResponseBody> loginRequest(@QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap);
```

Уже не знаю, мне нужен совет, сам не могу справиться. Буду очень признателен любой помощи или совету

Comment: По идее вам надо вот такой тип данных для ответа: `Response<ResponseBody>`. А искомый ответ сервера должен будет быть в `response.errorBody().string()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как я понял, надо сделать так?:
@POST("/v1/login")
Response<ResponseBody> loginRequest(@QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap);
А response.errorBody().string() уже в LoginRequest

Comment: Да, вроде верно.

Comment: ЮрийСПб проверю, отпишусь :)

Comment: ЮрийСПб, сделал 
@POST("/v1/login")
    Response<ResponseBody> loginRequest1(@QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap);

и далее вызвал

Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody> response = getService().loginRequest1(map);

В итоге ошибка:
DefaultRequestRunner.java:154: Thread-691 An exception occurred during request network execution :404 Not Found
                                                                             retrofit.RetrofitError: 404 Not Found

ругается на Response<okhttp3.ResponseBody> response = getService().loginRequest1(map);

Comment: При этом, когда выходит catch, поток 3 раза выполняется. Читал, что в `BaseSpiceService` в restAdapterBuilder надо прописать команду, чтоб 3 раза не вылолнялось. Когда вписал тот метод - система написала, что такого метода нет

Comment: Попробуйте без RoboSpice запросы делать. А то эта либа уже давно устарела)

Comment: ЮрийСПб RoboSpise вместо BaseSpiceServise?

Comment: ЮрийСПб, это библиотека, я понял. Там всё перелопачивать придётся, если RoboSpice (

Comment: Я имел в виду делать запросы как у вас в предпоследнем блоке кода сделано. Т.е. через OkHttp+Retrofit. Ответ должен по идее в onResponse придти и там надо не успешность запроса проверять а код ответа. И далее смотреть в body или errorBody

Comment: @ЮрийСПб до `onResponse` не доходит даже. Каршится на `Call<Response<ResponseBody>> myCall = getService().loginRequest1(map);` Интерфейс такой `@POST("/v1/login")
    Call<Response<com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody>> loginRequest1(@QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap);` Всё ещё пытаюсь методом тыка.. До этого делал `Response` вместо `Response<com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody>`

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/28892225/3212712 Там FormUrlEncoded и FieldMap

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, тот интерфейсный метод хочет принять 2е значение, и у меня загвостка, какие типы вписывать, точнее, с какими работать? Судя по комметам, у нас 2 разных варианта решения :(

Comment: Один через `Call<>/CallBack<>`, второй через `Response<ResponseBody>`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал так: ``

Comment: @ЮрийСПб **сделал так**: 
`getService().loginRequest2(map, new retrofit.Callback<Response>() {
@Override
public void success(Response response, retrofit.client.Response response2) {
 }
 @Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {}});`
**и так в интерфейсе:**
`@POST("/v1/login")
    void loginRequest2(@FieldMap Map<String, String> parameters, retrofit.Callback<Response> callback);`
срабатывает `onFailure` , но само тело не могу в строке вывести:
`error.getResponse().getBody()` отсюда. Правильно ли я сделал?

Comment: По идее вам надо не body, а errorBody. Приведите хотя бы ссылку скрипт ваш - а так мы в комментах ещё неделю вашу проблему решать будем

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как пример 'HTTP POST http://hoff.ru/api/v1/login?email=zayn1991%40gmail.com&password=4848848&device_id=5f45bee5151ac032&city=711' . мне кажется, errorBody метода там небыло, иначе я бы в дебаге его увидел. Это то, что Вы хотели узнать? Ссылку. Только это не гет, а пост запрос должен быть, по этой же ссылке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ сервера в случае ошибки лежит в `errorBody`. Вот пример вывода оного в логи:

```
public void test(){
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Retrofit retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    test test = retrofit.create(test.class);
    test.test().enqueue(new Callback<retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>> call, retrofit2.Response<retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>> response) {
            Log.d("onResponse response.body(): " + response.body());
            try {
                Log.e("onResponse response.errorBody(): " + response.errorBody().string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("onFailure: " + call);
        }
    });
}

interface test{
    @POST("http://hoff.ru/api/v1/login?email=zayn1991%40gmail.com&password=4848848&device_id=5f45bee5151ac032&city=711%27")
    Call<retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody>> test();
}
```

выведет:

> onResponse response.errorBody(): {"code":4,"message":"\u041f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0430\u043d \u043d\u0435\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u0430\u043c\u0435\u0442\u0440 \u043f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c"}

Comment: огромнейшее спасибо! только есть пара моментов по коду: его надо переделывать под себя(что я и сделал), ещё, так как у меня в проекте 2 версии retrofit, надо вручную писать `@POST `аннотации и выбирать retrofit2 =)

Comment: Ещё вопрос, на память, не могли бы Вы сказать, как отключить тройной запрос после неудачного ответа от сервера? Это не сильно важно, буду гуглить

Comment: Пожалуйста) Про тройной запрос не знаю - наверное надо поковырять настройки OkHttpClient.

Comment: я вас понял) поищу